# Why use static method in PHP's laravel model class?

Tags: php, design-patterns, laravel, singleton, static-methods

In PHP laravel, we have codes like

```
$user = User::find(1);
var_dump($user->name);
```

I am not concerning how to use the `find` method, I am concerning why laravel use a static method? Shouldn't the use of static method make the method hard to test?

Will it be better if they designed using singleton?

e.g.

```
$user = User::getInstance()->find(1);
var_dump($user->name);
```

Answer (score 24):

In fact, your example is very similar to what Laravel does behind the scene. When you do `User::find()`, you are actually asking for a new instance, either an instance of Collection or a QueryBuilder.

**Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model ([reference](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php)):**

```
public static function find($id, $columns = array('*'))
{
    if (is_array($id) && empty($id)) return new Collection;

    $instance = new static;

    return $instance->newQuery()->find($id, $columns);
}
```

---

As a side note, you'll also see another way of using static methods in Laravel e.g. `Input::get()`. These are called Facades.

> Facades provide a "static" interface to classes that are available in the application's IoC container ... Laravel "facades" serve as "static proxies" to underlying classes in the IoC container, providing the benefit of a terse, expressive syntax while maintaining more testability and flexibility than traditional static methods.
>
> When a user references any static method on the ... facade, Laravel resolves the cache binding from the IoC container and runs the requested method (in this case, get) against that object.

You can read more about Larave's Facades at: http://laravel.com/docs/facades

Comment: `class User extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`, `User` isn't a facade class

Comment: Right you spotted one huge mistake by me. Amended my answer.

Comment: Also, Facades (the design pattern) don't need to be static.

Comment: And how do we "*Mock*" the "`$user = User::find(1);`" call?

Comment: (Laravel is forced to provide some helper, becuase that is `static`, and can't be Mocked without direct support from Laravel's side.)

Answer (score 18):

Unnawut has a very good answer, however I felt it necessary to add in further explanation.

In your example

```
$user = User::find(1);
var_dump($user->name);
```

Laravel isn't using a static method, you are.  Another way to do this which you are probably looking for is to use dependency injection, which Laravel makes very easy because it can be done automatically.  So in whatever class you are using your `User` model in, you should be setting up something like this in the constructor...

```
public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}
```

And then you can modify your code to not use the static bindings.

```
$user = $this->user->find(1);
var_dump($user->name);
```

Comment: Whaaaat !! Can we do this with every facades ? Can I inject Mail facade and then do $this->mail->send ? *0*

Comment: Fantastic!  Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! Just starting with Laravel and this is reaaaaaaaally helpful man!

Comment: Is this right? I am so confused how this could work. Doesn't the typehint in the constructor tell Laravel to inject an instance of `User`? A `User` is an instance of an eloquent model which does not have a `find()` method. What am I missing here?

Comment: You are correct, it's not on the model class.  It's on the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` class.  But it's accessed through the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Eloquent\Model` class's `__callStatic` magic method.

Comment: @flyingL123 oh god, Laravel turned comments into actual code? this framework... smh

Answer (score 2):

This would restrict the system from only having one User. Whilst the `find` method may be static, the User class will have other methods and properties that aren't, a likely example is in your example: `$user->name`

A method that does not rely upon any instance variables,  I.e variables who's value is specific to the particular object instance, but instead provides generic functionality that applies to all instances, can, and probably should, be static. This is why the `$this` operator is illegal within static methods, as it can make no reference to a particular object instance.

Answer (score 0):

@unnawut reference link to the source code of Model.php is no longer using static `find` function as the class has been refactored. The function that get called eventually is in Builder.php ([source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php)),

The logic still same

```
- magic function `__callStatic` of Model class get called
- a new instance of Builder is created and return
- call the find method of the Builder instance
```

Model.php

```php
    public function newEloquentBuilder($query)
    {
        return new Builder($query);
    }
```

Builder.php

```php
    public function find($id, $columns = ['*'])
    {
        if (is_array($id) || $id instanceof Arrayable) {
            return $this->findMany($id, $columns);
        }

        return $this->whereKey($id)->first($columns);
    }
```