# What is the meaning of utility functions in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Good day to all, I am new to Laravel and the thing that I encountered with and cannot understand is utility methods that are used in the framework, for example, `Customer::all()` where Customer is model or `Customer::find()`. So, what is the point of utility methods and why `all()` and `find()` are static.

Comment: They’re not utility methods. They’re methods on **Eloquent models**, a _core_ concept in Laravel. Read the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent

Comment: What @MartinBean said is correct. Utility methods is properly known in Laravel as "Helper methods": https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers

Comment: Hope this link will answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24879567/why-use-static-method-in-phps-laravel-model-class

Comment: @aceraven777 They’re not even helper methods. `::all()` and `::find()` on a `Customer` object would be Eloquent methods. Working with models is one of the first things OP should have read up on and then wouldn’t have this question.

Comment: @MartinBean I'm NOT saying `::all` and `::find` are helper methods. What i'm saying is utility and helper methods are synonyms. Based what you said `::all` and `::find` are eloquent static methods

Comment: @aceraven777, thank you for your explanation, I just want to understand why helper methods are static and what if they would be non static. Yes I know if it is static it means we do not have to create instance of class just to simplify our lives. Is that right?

Comment: @Mirasan does it make sense to have `find` be non-static? Being non-static means you need to have an instance of an object which means either creating a new model or finding an existing one.

Comment: @apokryfos, so , the reason why all() and find() are static it is because to free developer from creating an instance. In a nutshell, to make the life of developer easier. Is that correct? I hope you will answer:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utility functions in general offer some sort of utility, i.e. functionality which is usually just for convenience and can also be achieved by following a set of steps.

For example `Model::find()` is functionality that can also be achieved by creating a query builder object and then performing a query e.g.

```
Model::getQuery()->where('id', '=', $id)->first();
```

For convenience you can just do `Model::find($id)` which is shorter and more intuitive.

It is static because it does not make sense for it not to be static. A non-static method requires an instance of the class however in ORMs an instance of a class corresponds to a potential database entry (which either exists or could exist). 
Therefore since `find` is used to retrieve a database entry it makes no sense to require a backing database entry in order to use it.

In short what this means is, if you execute method `$object = Model::find(1)` you will get back a model which corresponds to database entry with identifier `1`. There is a 1 to 1 mapping of the PHP object to the relational object. If make changes to `$object` and call `$object->save()` then changes will be persisted in the database (i.e. `$object` already exists). If on the other hand you do `$object = new Model()` you will get back a new model which does not currently correspond to a database entry. However calling `$object->save()` will make that object correspond to a new database entry and it will be updated accordingly (i.e. the new object could exist). If a framework required you to make a "dummy" object just to access some helper methods there's always a chance that (either by omission or through unknown side-effects) `save()` gets called on that dummy object and you end up filling up your database with what is essentially junk.

The takeaway from this is that in an ORM it does not make sense to create a model instance if you don't intend to store it in the database. Laravel does not strictly obey this rule, but in general it does, and you should too.

The same applies to `all` which gets all database entries. It doesn't make sense to get all database entries by requiring to first get one entry.

Same applies to `getQuery` used above which returns a query builder instance. Note that most people don't actually use `getQuery` because it runs implicitly when someone uses something like e.g. `Model::where(..)` so technically `Model::where()` is also a utility. I mention this because when you see something like `Model::where('id', $id)->where('name', $name)` the 2nd where is after a `->` which implies it's on an instance rather than static, however that instance is actually a query builder instance and not a model instance.

Comment: great explanation but if it is ok for you can you please clarify what you mean by  ORMs an instance of a class corresponds to a potential database entry (which either exists or could exist). Therefore since find is used to retrieve a database entry it makes no sense to require a backing database entry in order to use it. I hope for your answer. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I've added a paragraph, but in short in an Object-relational mapping (ORM) I find it very bad practice to have an object which shouldn't actually map to a relational row under any circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `User::find()` , you are actually asking for a new instance, either an instance of [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections) or a [QueryBuilder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries).

Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model : https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php

As a side note, you'll also see another way of using static methods in Laravel e.g. `Input::get()`. These are called Facades.

Facades provide a "static" interface to classes that are available in the application's IoC container ... Laravel "facades" serve as "static proxies" to underlying classes in the IoC container, providing the benefit of a terse, expressive syntax while maintaining more testability and flexibility than traditional static methods.

When a user references any static method on the ... facade, Laravel resolves the cache binding from the IoC container and runs the requested method (in this case, get) against that object.

You can read more about Laravel Facades at: http://laravel.com/docs/facades

Answer (score 1):

> Laravel includes a variety of global "helper" PHP functions. Many of
>   these functions are used by the framework itself; however, you are
>   free to use them in your own applications if you find them convenient.

So, basically, helpers in Laravel are built-in utility functions that you can call from anywhere within your application. If they hadn't been provided by the core framework, you might have ended up developing your own helper classes.

Although the core provides a variety of helpers already, there’s always a chance that you’ll need your own and would like to develop one so you don’t have to repeat the same code here and there, thus enforcing better maintainability.

Comment: `all()` and `find()` are not helper functions though.

Comment: but where i mentioned that the all() and find() are helper functions

Answer (score 1):

all() find() where() etc.. these methods are not utility methods, they are orm methods and coming from Query Builder.

They are static so they provide you using them without creating an instance

Comment: Tingir, hi dude, so you mean all(), find(), where() are static just to make the life of the developer easier by letting him or her not create instance of the class Is that right? What if those methods would be non static. Would that be ok?

Comment: @Mirasan when you create an instance of class, it's fill some space on your ram. So using these static methods provide you more available space on ram. Because they're not belong any instance, they are belong class itself.. If your website have high traffic, creating new instances might slow down your server

Comment: @Mirasan  find() and where() methods are not static but could be called as static thanks to through __callStatic() method inside Builder::class

Answer (score 1):

Those methods are part of the Eloquent system and help you to retrieve records from your database.

The `all` method gets *all* of the records for the given model from the database and returns a `Collection` of instances of that model. If you were to do `User::all()`, a collection of every single user in your database would be returned as a `Collection` of `User` objects.

```
$users = User::all(); // Returns a Collection of User objects
foreach ($users as $user) {
    // Here, each $user will be an instance of User
}
```

The `find` method is used to find a model in the database by its primary key. This method actually returns a single model instance if it finds a record matching the given primary key, or `null` if it doesn't find anything.

```
$user = User::find(1); // Find a User with the primary key 1, or null
```

Those methods aren't actually static, though you can use them as if they were. The `find` method is a non-static method on the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` object and the `all` method is a utility method on `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` which eventually calls the `Builder` object's `get` method.

When you call `User::find(1)`, Laravel will create a new query or a `Builder` object and call the `find` method on the `Builder` which will return you a new `User` object, or null. Similarly, when calling `User::all()`, Laravel will create a new query or `Builder` object and call the `get()` method which will return your collection of models.

The `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class uses the `__callStatic` magic method to redirect static method calls for non-existent static methods to the `Builder` object. That's how you're able to call them in a static context:

```
public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
{
    return (new static)->$method(...$parameters);
}
```

So you could effectively do this to achieve the same results:

```
$user = (new User)->find(1);
$allUsers = (new User)->get();
```